# Bootstrap how to check if image was resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize

I am using bootstrap row-fluid with images in it. Dimensions of this images changes when the browser window changes so is there any event listener that triggers when image resize happens? I want it to use to get image width. I have tried this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img.product-thumbnail').resize(function(){
        alert($('img.product-thumbnail').width());
    });
});
```

and my img tags are:

```
<img src="img/produkt1.png" title="Názov produktu" class="product-thumbnail">
<img src="img/produkt2.png" title="Názov produktu" class="product-thumbnail">
```

5 images total. Right now I am not getting any alerts but I know that img changed its size (chrome dev tools > show dimensions). Is there any way to acomplish this? (jquery is included so there shouldnt be problem with selectors)

Comment: AFAIK you'll need a generic window resize handler that figures out if the image width changed (since the last time the handler ran, or from the original width)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any really easy way of doing this.  The [jQuery resize() event](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) is intended to capture window resize events rather than listen on individual elements.

With that in-mind, and for the sake of an easy explanation, allow me to suggest this:

1) On window load, grab the image dimensions and stick them into a `data-` attribute:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('img.product-thumbnail').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        // get the image dimensions 
        thisWidth = $this.width(),
        thisHeight = $this.height();

        // push them into an attribute 
        $(this).attr('data-width', thisWidth);
        $(this).attr('data-height', thisHeight);
    });
});
```

2) Tie an event to the Window resize and check:

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    // loop over each, checking dimensions
    $('img.product-thumbnail').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            // get the image dimensions 
            thisWidth = $this.width(),
            thisHeight = $this.height();

       //check that there are data-attribtues before going further
       if($this.attr('data-height').length){
           if(thisWidth !== $this.attr('data-width')){
               //width has changed
           }
           if(thisHeight !== $this.attr('data-height')){
               //height has changed
           }
       }
    }
});
```

This is very quick, untested, and unoptimised code but the theory behind it is solid and should help give you a good starting-point for detecting whether an image has changed size.

Comment: I have tried writing an event listener that listens to window size change and it worked but It uses a lot of computer speed because event happens every time I change windows size (every 1 pixel). So if I change it by 50px event fires 50 times and I wanted to avoid this. However if it is not possible I must try to do it some other way.

Comment: As I mention: it's not optimised in any way.  You are correct that it would fire every time though.  I assume from your question that's also what you expected `image.resize` to do?  You could optimise this very easily by tying it into your CSS break-points (using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for example) - and then only check the image dimensions when you know you've gone through a break-point.  That still doesn't avoid the fact that you're listening for, and acting upon each `$(window).resize` event.